# Apple Business Manager API?

Tags: ipad, mdm, workato, apple-business-manager

Maybe a quick and easy one here but, does anyone know if ABM has an independent API or which API it utilizes? If so, would be a big help as I am trying to automate removing machines from ABM when we no longer need them.